# How to control CustomScrollView inside CustomScrollView?

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I have widget tree which contains top-level CustomScrollView with SliverFillRemaining inside. SliverFillRemaining may contain another CustomScrollView (see picture).

[image]

I want to prevent scrolling of nested CustomScrollView until SliverFillRemaining  will fill all viewport (because of top-level CustomScrollView).
In other words I want expandable TabVeiws with scrollable grid inside.

Comment: Take a look at [NestedScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html).

Comment: @Yann39 Oh, Gods! Thank you! It's what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yann39 noted, [NestedScrollView widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) solves this issue perfectly. Code sample in class documentation illustrates what to do.